# All flags and registers set to execute interrupt and doesn´t happen

Tags: interrupt, avr

I have written a code for AVR Tiny 44 to execute ainteruption for  timer compare routine
All registers are set, all flags ok in the AVR studio simulator but the interuption never happens

what am I missing

```
SEI
    LDI R16,0B00000001
    OUT  TCCR0B,R16 ; SET THE TIMER GO 

CYCLE:
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP

    RJMP CYCLE
```

Comment: AIN:
 CLI
 clr r16
 out spl,r16
 ldi r16,0x6f
 out sph,r16

 rcall conf_initial
 CLR R16
 OUT MCUSR,R16
 ORI R16,0B00100000
 OUT MCUCR,R16

 SEI
 LDI R16,0B00000001
 OUT  TCCR0B,R16 ; SET THE TIMER GO

Comment: There is no timer interrupt enabled (in TIMSK0), and no interrupt handler in your code. What do you expect to happen when timer compare happens?

Comment: Sorry all code was not allowed . the issue was in AVRSTUDIO in Tools-Tools settings- mask interrupts while stepping - true change to false

Answer (score -1):

conf_initial:

```
ldi r16,0b11110000  ;both compares in set when compare
out TCCR0A,r16
clr r16
out TCNT0,r16
ldi r16,0x0f
out OCR0A,r16   ;TEMP COMPARE TO 0F B
out OCR0B,r16   ;TIME COMPATE TO 0F A 
LDI R16,0B00000111
OUT TIMSK0,R16
SBI DDRA,7
SBI DDRB,2

RET
```